# I want to use qulifier <large> in android studio,but I can't add the directory layout-large

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a fresher in android.In my tutorial book(
A little outdated) teaching in Eclipse,It just add a directory `layout-large` to code another layout xml files to adapt big screen.

I use android studio,when I add the directory,it says:
[image]

and add the `layout-large`directory:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a different way to use qulifier to adapt big screen in adroid studio?

Comment: I use crtl+shif+N also can't find the directory

Comment: switch the project view from "Android" to "Project" and check your res/ folder if it already contains the layout-large or not. if not, you can create it using : File => New Directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the folder in the `/res` directory using your file explorer.

Or you can try switching to `Project` view in stead of `Android` to do this inside Android Studio as visible in this screenshot:

[image]

When in project view all different resource folders are visible in your IDE, while in Android view, these get visualized in what appears to be a single folder.

[image]

Once you see this, you can right-click on the `res` folder and select `new>Android Resource Directory`

There you can add different types of resource paramater to new folders.
These resource parameters can be for Locale, density or as in your case screen size.

[image]

Comment: Yeah! When I switch to projext view, I see that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information on how you can add the folders inside Android Studio and on the different resource type parameters. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Switch your Project view with option "Project" not for "Android" you will see the folder.